# iOS bluetooth pairing dialog "eaten" by dispatch_sync call

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, flutter, bluetooth

I have an interesting problem.  I'm working on a BTLE library and am coming across the old iOS BT pairing dialog wall.. Best part is I have an entirely functioning solution in a small iOS demo.  Everything functions as expected in said demo, we address the BT pairing dialog and have visibility into the users choice of "Pair" or "Cancel."  After our "connect" call we have our desired connection state based on the user interaction.  However when finally integrating with a Flutter app we run the connect call in a background task (functioning demo is in main thread i believe) and the BT pairing dialog never displays to the user.. Note if i use the commented out "dispatch_async" approach i do indeed get the dialog, but the connected state always returns false as execution returns and completes prior to a user getting to finish the dialog.

```
if([@"connect2Device" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        NSString *mac_Address = call.arguments[@"address"];
        //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0), ^{
            
            BleConnection connection;
            
            @try {
            connection = [self->ConnectionController connect: mac_Address];
            } @catch(NSException *exception) {
            result([FlutterError errorWithCode: exception.name message: exception.reason details:exception.userInfo]);
            }
            if(connection != nil) {
                if (connection.isConnected == true) {
                    NSLog(@"connection is true, returning YES from plugin");
                    result(@YES);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"connection is true, returning NO from plugin");
                    result(@NO);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Any ideas as to why the dialog is hidden by the dispatch_sycn call?  I've tried using all the queue types defined.. From what i'm reading as long as you write to an encrypted characteristic iOS auto-prompts user w/ this dialog, no "real" code required.  I *think* I'm familiar w/ this approach as that's how i ultimately determine what choice the user made (via WriteWithNotify).

Comment: Why are you using a `dispatch_sync` anyway?  BLE write operations are asynchronous.  You shouldn't attempt to make them synchronous.  You need to use a completion handler, callback or delegation technique.

Comment: @Paul11- thanks for the reply.  I'm new to iOS/objective-c and BT :) so I'm essentially trying to make sense of this all myself.  I'm only using dispatch_sync b/c in terms of my observations, using that method causes the ConnectionController connect() to block until completion (so connect doesn't return immediately which is what I want, it should "connect" for 30 seconds to allow the user to acknowledge the pairing dialog.  If I use dispatch_async I do see the pairing dialog, but connect returns immediately after called.   I'm about to test a new impl for the connect code, i'll keep ya posted

Comment: That is your problem. This sort of function can't "return" a value. The operation is asynchronous. http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/. This is a very common paradigm in mobile development. I have never worked with flutter but it must have some way of handling it

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  Ultimately had to change what took place on the BTLE library side of things in the open call... SLEEP BABY SLEEP until we see the notifyCharacterstic associated w/ the pairing dialog choice.

Really appreciate the speedy responses @Paul11, we're good over here!